# Users able to see others' details. FirstOrDefault returning the wrong record? Or caching issue? Help! :)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Users of my site have experienced some strange behaviour yesterday (first time I've seen this issue), and unfortunately I don't have much in the way of error logs to try to figure out what's going on.  The site had a higher-than-normal number of people online at once, albeit not a large number in the grand scheme of things (maybe 50 to 100 users all trying to perform similar functions).  I can't recreate the issue in my development environment, haven't seen it before, and don't really know why it is happening.

The crux of the problem is that users can register or log on successfully, but a small number of them could see other users' data.

The site is ASP.NET MVC 3.

Users are logging on and I set an authentication cookie - here's the LogOn action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(AccountLogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("login-message", "Incorrect username or password");
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            Session.Remove("MenuItems");
            return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        }
        else
        {
            model.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

AccountLogOnViewModel is a simple object with two string properties, UserName and Password.

From what I can gather, this is fine - if you log in as NickW then doing something like User.Identity.Name correctly gives you "NickW" (when users were seeing other users' data, they reported that that "Welcome, NickW" text on screen was showing them the correct value - this is written out using User.Identity.Name)

The site also uses a custom membership provider.  It overrides the ValidateLogin method, and the GetUser method.  ValidateLogin appears to be working just fine so I'm not concerned about it.

The overridden GetUser method is as follows:

```
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        User user = _userRepository.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
        MembershipUser membershipUser = null;

        if (user == null)
            return membershipUser;

        membershipUser = new MembershipUser(this.Name,
            user.UserName,
            user.Id,
            user.Email,
            null,
            user.Comments,
            user.IsActivated,
            user.IsLockedOut,
            user.CreatedDate,
            user.LastLoginDate,
            user.LastLoginDate,
            user.LastModifiedDate,
            Convert.ToDateTime(user.LastLockedOutDate));

        return membershipUser;
    }
```

So I'm attempting to retrieve a User object from my database, and using that to create a new MembershipUser object.  My database User table has additional columns on top of those required by the membership provider - e.g. name, address, phone number etc.

At various points in the rest of the website (for example if you go to the Profile page), I retrieve a user object from the database and use it to populate the screen.  The line I use to retrieve the User object is:

```
User user = userRepository.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == Membership.GetUser().UserName);
```

Here is a cut down version of the userRepository (i.e. just removing unrelated code).

```
public class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private Table<User> usersTable;
    private string _connectionString;

    public SqlUserRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        usersTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<User>();
    }


    public IQueryable<User> Users
    {
        get { return usersTable; }
    }

    public void CreateUser(AccountRegisterViewModel user)
    {
        User newUser = new User();

        newUser.UserName = user.UserName;
        newUser.Salutation = user.Salutation;
        newUser.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
        newUser.SecondaryPhoneNumber = user.SecondaryPhoneNumber;
        newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        newUser.PasswordSalt = CreateSalt();
        newUser.Password = CreatePasswordHash(user.Password, newUser.PasswordSalt);
        newUser.Email = user.Email;
        newUser.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        newUser.Comments = "Created from web registration";
        newUser.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        newUser.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        newUser.IsActivated = true;
        newUser.IsLockedOut = false;
        newUser.MayContact = user.MayContact;

        usersTable.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
        usersTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

So it appears to me as if the auth cookie I'm setting is fine, but either:
When I first go in to the membership provider's GetUser() method, it retrieves the wrong record from the database and therefore sets up a MembershipUser object with the wrong username; subsequently when I look in the database for "this" user I'm actually looking for the wrong username.

Or: Intermittently when I do userRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == Membership.GetUser().Name) it retrieves the wrong record.

Or: something else is going wrong that I haven't thought of.

As I say, this seems to be a problem when the site was under load, so I'm wondering if it's some sort of caching issue somewhere?  But I really don't know.

One thought I had was to change the way I retrieve the user in case the problem lies with the membership provider, and use this instead:

```
userRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
// or HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name if not within a controller
```

But really I'm not even sure what's going on so have no idea whether this will resolve the issue.  Could it be a caching problem somewhere?  It appears (but I can't be 100% certain) that when user A could see user B's details, it was always the case that user B was also active in the system (or had been within the previous 20 minutes).

I know it's a long shot, but does anyone have any idea how this could happen?  Obviously it's a major concern and needs to be fixed urgently, but without knowing why it's happening I can't fix it!

Thanks in advance for any help,
Nick

Comment: How does your Userrepository get instantiated?

Comment: What does it mean that users see other users data? Do they log in as other users? Or rather, one of your specific views returns wrong data and it has nothing to do with correct authentication?

Comment: When I say that users see others' data, I mean that when I log in as NickW, my authentication cookie is correct and says I'm NickW.  But if I go to my "profile" page on the website, my code retrieves a User record from the database and populates the page with that data - e.g. phone number, first and last name etc.  To do this I do userRepository.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == Membership.GetUser().Name).  So I would expect this to bring back NickW's data.  However, when the problem occurred yesterday, the code would actually return me, say, WiktorZ's data from the database instead.

Comment: rene, userRepository is injected using StructureMap.

Comment: Grant, usernames are unique (unique key in the database)

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

1. Instead of using `FirstOrDefault`, use `SingleOrDefault`. `FirstOrDefault` assumes there will be more than 1 record of data matching your query. Since you are querying by username, there should only be 1 matching row, correct? In that case, use `SingleOrDefault` instead. When there are multiple rows that match the query, `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception.
2. To get the username, instead of invoking `Membership.GetUser().UserName`, use `User.Identity.Name`. The `User` property on an MVC controller references an `IPrincipal` that  should match the user's forms authentication cookie value. Since you have a custom membership provider, this should help eliminate its methods as a source of the problem.
3. There could be a caching issue if you have caching set up for the MVC project. Do you use the `OutputCacheAttribute` (`[OutputCache]`) on any controllers or action methods? Do you have it set up as a global filter in the global.asax file? Or do you think there may be some kind of SQL-based caching going on?
4. Looking at your overridden `GetUser` method, I see it should take 2 parameters: `string username` and `bool isOnline`. However, when you invoke it with `Membership.GetUser().UserName`, you are passing no parameters. Do you have another overridden overload of this method that also takes no parameters? What does it look like? Does it use `System.Threading.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` to sniff out the current username when none is passed?

Comment: Dan, thanks a lot.  1:  I used FirstOrDefault as I was led to believe it performed better than SingleOrDefault? I've checked and there are no records with the same username in the database, but I'll look into whether that change is a good idea anyway.  2: Thanks for clarifying that.  I wondered whether I should use User.Identity.Name instead, good to have it confirmed that this is the preferred option.  3: No OutputCacheAttribute anywhere.  I wondered if somehow my repository was caching data, but don't know enough about LinqToSQL to know if that's a likely candidate or not?

Comment: ... I've read that in LinqToSQL you should keep the DataContext alive as briefly as possible, which isn't how my repositories are coded, so I'm wondering if that's the culprit and I should change my repository to create / dispose of a new context each time I perform some work?   4: Must confess the membership provider was inherited from elsewhere and I'm not very familiar with it.  But there's no overridden method with no parameters (so I assume it uses the base MembershipProvider's implementation).   Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Yes, definitely dispose of your data context after you use it. You should not keep it around for any longer than 1 HTTP request. I am not familiar with StructureMap, but most IoC containers have the ability to handle this kind of lifetime scoping for you. When it comes to First vs Single or default, performance should not concern you. The bottleneck will be the SQL database, not the LinqToSql provider. These are different methods with different purposes, and when you expect only 1 record to exist, do not use FirstOrDefault.